Video call camera
I am working on an android app that uses Twilio Video to connect based on meeting room previously created. When the user access the camera the first time, android is requesting the permission and I am able to select "While using app".
When I select this option, camera video is working correctly. But the next time app camera is not streaming video.
Camera is working only if I set" Deny" permission and provide the permission once again while using the app. In short, app is unable to recognize the camera permission we have provided.i did not seen any error in firebase crashlytics.
I have provided all the required permission code. See below my permission setting. I have been struck with this issue for last few days, any help will be appreciated.
Dependencies:
twilio_programmable_video: ^1.1.1 &
permission_handler: ^10.4.5
  void connect() async {
    print('[ APPDEBUG ] ConferenceRoom.connect()'); 
    try 
        { 
        await TwilioProgrammableVideo.setAudioSettings( bluetoothPreferred: false, speakerphoneEnabled: false, ); 
        List<CameraSource> cameraSources = [];
        cameraSources = await CameraSource.getSources();
      var cameraCapturer = CameraCapturer(
        cameraSources.firstWhere((source) => source.isFrontFacing),
      );
      List<LocalVideoTrack> videoTrack;
      if (type == 'audio') {
        videoTrack = [LocalVideoTrack(false, cameraCapturer)];
      } else {
        videoTrack = [LocalVideoTrack(true, cameraCapturer)];
      }
      isCameraFrontFacing = true;
      trackId = Uuid().v4();

  var connectOptions = ConnectOptions(
    token,
    roomName: name,
    audioTracks: [LocalAudioTrack(true, 'audio_track-$trackId')],
    videoTracks: videoTrack,
    enableNetworkQuality: true,
    networkQualityConfiguration: NetworkQualityConfiguration(
      remote: NetworkQualityVerbosity.NETWORK_QUALITY_VERBOSITY_MINIMAL,
        ),
    enableDominantSpeaker: true,
  );

  room = await TwilioProgrammableVideo.connect(connectOptions);

  _streamSubscriptions.add(room.onConnected.listen(_onConnected));
  _streamSubscriptions.add(room.onDisconnected.listen(_onDisconnected));
  _streamSubscriptions.add(room.onReconnecting.listen(_onReconnecting));
  _streamSubscriptions.add(room.onConnectFailure.listen(_onConnectFailure));
} catch (err) {
  print('[ APPDEBUG ] Error connecting: $err');
  emit(ConferenceError(err.toString()));
}
}

 Future<void> initializeVideoCall() async { 
try { 
    await Permission.camera.request(); // Check if permissions have been requested before final cameraStatus = await Permission.camera.status; 

    final audioStatus = await Permission.microphone.status;

  if (cameraStatus.isGranted && audioStatus.isGranted) {
    print(cameraStatus);
    print("Camera and microphone permissions already granted.");
    await _conferenceCubit.connect();
    print("Successfully connected to the conference.");
  } else {
    // Request permissions only if they are not already granted
    final status = await Future.wait([
      Permission.camera.request(),
      Permission.microphone.request(),
    ]);

    if (status[0].isGranted && status[1].isGranted) {
      print("Camera and microphone permissions granted.");
      await _conferenceCubit.connect();
      print("Successfully connected to the conference.");
    } else {
      print("Camera and/or microphone permissions are not granted.");
    }
  }
} catch (e) {
  print("Error initializing video call: $e");
}

}

Error Image
